# $\chi^2$-test vs. sum of square differences test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Let $\mathbf{x} := (x_0,\cdots,x_{N-1})$ be a $N$-tuple of elements of a finite set $\mathcal{X}$, and let $p$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal{X}$ that we assume to be nonzero everywhere.

The $T$-statistic (used in the $\chi^2$-test) is defined as $T(\mathbf{x}) := N \sum_{x \in X} \frac{\left(\frac{\vert \{k \ \vert \ x_k = x\}\vert}{N} - p_x\right)^2}{p_x}$.

Then it can be shown that if $(X_0,\cdots, X_{N-1})$ is an iid sequence, then $T(\mathbf{X})$ converges, in law, and when $N \to \infty$, to a $\chi^2(\vert \mathcal{X} \vert - 1)$ law, from which one builds the $\chi^2$-test.

Let us also consider the *sum of square differences* statistic (**is it the official name?** I learnt it from [this paper](http://www.johnmorrow.info/projects/benford/benfordMain.pdf) but I'm sure many more statisticians have thought of this a long time ago...) defined by $SSD(\mathbf{X}) := N \sum_{x \in X} \left(\frac{\vert \{k \ \vert \ x_k = x\}\vert}{N} - p_x\right)^2$.

Then it can also be shown that if $(X_0,\cdots, X_{N-1})$ is an iid sequence, then the law of $SSD(\mathbf{X})$ converges, when $N \to \infty$, to some law that depends on $p$ (I don't know if it has a name, but it can be easily tabulated by a computer), and we can similarly devise a test for this statistic.

My questions are: **is one of these tests "better" than the other? If so, in what sense, and why? Which one should be used in what context?**

**More generally, given two tests sharing the same purpose, what is the natural way of comparing them?**

EDIT: I have just thought of something: the (limiting) law of $T$ does **not** depend on $p$, whereas the (limiting) law of $SSD$ does. Therefore, the $\chi^2$-test has the advantage that it is only necessary to tabulate **a single law** for all probabilities $p$. In the time of Pearson, this was probably a tremendous advantage. But how about now?

Comment: Can you give us a citation or link for the *sum of square differences test* ?

Comment: I personally learnt it from http://www.johnmorrow.info/projects/benford/benfordMain.pdf but I thought it was something well-known. I mean, this $SSD$ obviously converges, in law (under the hypothesis saying that the $X_i$ are independent of law $p$) to the law of the squared-norm of a Gaussian vector with known covariance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. I think yes in the time of Pearson the huge of advantage of the chi-squared test was that, asymptotically, it approximates a known distribution.

One of the problems with the alternative you suggest is that it goes by many different names. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1431) it's referred to as goodness-of-fit test based on Euclidean distance. A [revised version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0042) was later published using the term "root mean square" test. I'm sure you could find other papers that discuss this test under other names.

The first paper is a good starting place. In some cases, this test is superior to the chi-squared test, especially in a test that involves many cells with expectations near zero. Furthermore, the fact that the distribution has to be simulated isn't really a concern now given modern computing.

Comment: Thank you for the references. I will take a look! I will wait a few days before accepting your answer since the question has not received a lot of attention.